# Spring tool suite: How to set editor JavaScript for *.js file?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Spring tool suite: How to set editor JavaScript for `*.js` file?

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.8.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202009151856
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please open JavaScript files with the `Generic Editor`. This will provide you with all the nice features of the JavaScript/TypeScript language tooling that comes with the language server from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This is Spring Tools Suite 4, not Visual Studio Code. Are you missing?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. In case you download and use the Spring Tools 4 distribution from https://spring.io/tools, the Eclipse Wild Web Developer components are pre-installed, which integrate the underlying Visual Studio Code JavaScript/TypeScript code smartness into Eclipse. If you installed the Spring Tools 4 into an existing Eclipse, you would need to manually install the Eclipse Wild Web Developer tools (from the main Eclipse repo).